# Disallow queuing of requests in gRPC microservices

Tags: python-asyncio, grpc, grpc-python, grpc-go, linkerd

SetUp:
We have gRPC pods running in a k8s cluster. The service mesh we use is linkerd. Our gRPC microservices are written in python (asyncio grpcs as the concurrency mechanism), with the exception of the entry-point. That microservice is written in golang (using gin framework). We have an AWS API GW that talks to an NLB in front of the golang service. The golang service communicates to the backend via nodeport services.

Requests on our gRPC Python microservices can take a while to complete. Average is 8s, up to 25s in the 99th %ile. In order to handle the load from clients, we've horizontally scaled, and spawned more pods to handle concurrent requests.

Problem:
When we send multiple requests to the system, even sequentially, we sometimes notice that requests go to the same pod as an ongoing request. What can happen is that this new request ends up getting "queued" in the server-side (not fully "queued", some progress gets made when context switches happen). The issue with queueing like this is that:

1. The earlier requests can start getting starved, and eventually timeout (we have a hard 30s cap from API GW).
2. The newer requests may also not get handled on time, and as a result get starved.

The symptom we're noticing is 504s which are expected from our hard 30s cap.

What's strange is that we have other pods available, but for some reason the loadbalancer isn't routing it to those pods smartly. It's possible that linkerd's smarter load balancing doesn't work well for our high latency situation (we need to look into this further, however that will require a big overhaul to our system).

One thing I wanted to try doing is to stop this queuing up of requests. I want the service to immediately reject the request if one is already in progress, and have the client (meaning the golang service) retry. The client retry will hopefully hit a different pod (do let me know if that won’t happen). In order to do this, I set the "maximum_concurrent_rpcs" to 1 on the server-side (Python server). When i sent multiple requests in parallel to the system, I didn't see any RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED exceptions (even under the condition when there is only 1 server pod). What I do notice is that the requests are no longer happening in parallel on the server, they happen sequentially (I think that’s a step in the right direction, the first request doesn’t get starved). That being said, I’m not seeing the RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED error in golang. I do see a delay between the entry time in the golang client and the entry time in the Python service. My guess is that the queuing is now happening client-side (or potentially still server side, but it’s not visible to me)?

I then saw online that it may be possible for requests to get queued up on the client-side as a default behavior in http/2. I tried to test this out in custom Python client that mimics the golang one with:

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
    "<some address>",
    options=[("grpc.max_concurrent_streams", 1)]
)
# create stub to server with channel…
```

However, I'm not seeing any change here either. (Note, this is a test dummy client - eventually i'll need to make this run in golang. Any help there would be appreciated as well).

Questions:

1. How can I get the desired effect here? Meaning server sends resource exhausted if already handling a request, golang client retries, and it hits a different pod?
2. Any other advice on how to fix this issue? I'm grasping at straws here.

Thank you!